# Core Bluetooth: Find out if device is available for reconnection

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use the `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method to try to connect to a previously connected peripheral. Connection attempts will only succeed when the peripheral is in vicinity of the iOS device.

Now, how do I figure out if the known peripheral is in vicinity and therefore connectable in the near future?

If you have a look at the Core Bluetooth guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html) and scroll down to Figure 5.1 Apple describes a possible reconnection flow. In the first column of that diagram theres a conditional "*Device available?*" What method or member does reflect this availability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Device available?" box is referring to `centralManager(_:didConnect:)` having been called. If you look at the box above, it's "Try to connect." If it's successful, then the device is available.

This is almost always the correct approach. Don't ask "is this likely to succeed?" Just try. If it works, it works.

If you really want to know nearby but unconnected devices, then you can scan for them if they're advertising using `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)`. You can then check if any discovered peripherals are the one you're looking for.

Of course a device might be nearby and not advertising. It might be connected to another device, in which case you can't see it. It might be connected to your device, in which case you'll need `retrieveConnectedPeripherals` to see it. It might just be not advertising (many devices stop advertising after a period of time). In that case you can't see it without trying to connect to it.

But generally the right answer is to just try to connect if you know the device already. Set a timeout, and if it times out, it's probably not nearby. Or don't set a timeout, and just let it try to connect until it works.

Comment: Thank you. The problem I had with this box is that CB actually does not tell me if the device is potentially available to connect. Like you wrote, `scanForPeripherals:` is the only way to know. It does make sense to me now more and more, I just assumed that there was another way CB offered to make the process more efficient speed- and energy-wise, which is not the case. What's important to add here imho is that the `connect:` method will not time out. That means that neither `_:didConnect:` nor `_:didFailToConnect:error:` will be called if the device is not physically ready to connect to.

Comment: Correct; that's why you need to set a timeout if you care about that. A BLE connection can take an indefinite amount of time (days, weeks, anything) without it being considered a problem. This isn't really an issue of CB, BTW. It's related to how BLE works (and in truth, all networking). In the absence of something sending out packets (and thus spending energy), there's no way to know that it exists.